# Is it OK to leave an in-ground sprinkler "winterized" all summer?

Tags: sprinkler-system

My parents have an in-ground sprinkler system. It was winterized last fall.

My father passed away and my mother is thinking of just not using it this year.

We're wondering if leaving it "winterized" until next spring (1 year from now) would do any damage to it.

Answer (score 7):

You'll be fine.  Winterized involves removing all of the water from the system so the pipes don't explode from the freezing temperature. Empty pipes during the warm summer won't be a problem.